# Laravel : when i return styled string from database its appear with the html tags

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

I store in the database some text with html tags using ckeditor , and when i print the text in laravel blade the text appears styled but the tags appears with the text check the process below .

This is the stored text in mysql database :

```
<h4>English</h4>
```

And this is the div section in the blade where the text printed

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
       {{$post->title_ar}} 
 </div>
```

And this is the result

```
<h3> English </h3>
```

i want the text appear without tags like this :

#### English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you change your syntax from `{{ }}` to `{!! !!}`.

It also depends what version you are using...

V-5 Should be: `{!! !!}`

Comment: No problem mate ! @E-housmaMardini

Answer (score 1):

use `{!! !!}` not `{{ }}`, it will work with you.